# Add 90 days to a given date using Python 3 - I keep getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'm learning the Python 3 basics and this is a homework question, I thought it was simple but I'm definitely missing it. I have searched for solutions and can't seem to find anything that DOESN't start with today's date but just any given date.

This exercise is utilizing 'import datetime' and returns the new date 90 days from a given date.

My code is this:

```
def add90Days(year, month, day):
     given_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
     new_date = given_date + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
     return new_date
```

The error is this:

```
TypeError: add90Days() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'month' and 'day'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

OR

```
def add90Days(date):
    given_date = datetime.date(date)
    new_date = given_date + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
    return new_date
```

with this error:

TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)

Process finished with exit code 1

Edit:

```
import datetime
```

## Complete this function to add ninety days to the given date, return the new date

```
 def add90Days(date):
     given_date = datetime.date(date)
     new_date = given_date + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
     return new_date
```

## expected output: 2018-12-30

print(add90Days(datetime.date(2018, 10, 1)))

## expected output: 2015-05-12

print(add90Days(datetime.date(2015, 2, 11)))

The calls are prewritten in the exercise as the expected output. I wrote the function but the "def add90days(date)" was prewritten as a starting point for the exercise

Comment: Please include full tracebacks. Also show how you're calling the functions

Comment: This is entirely about what you are sending to that function.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rxnrp/PycharmProjects/HelloPython/hellopython.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(add90Days(datetime.date(2018, 10, 1)))
  File "C:/Users/rxnrp/PycharmProjects/HelloPython/hellopython.py", line 6, in add90Days
    given_date = datetime.date(date)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)

Comment: @s11m00ne Please edit it into the question body; comments can be cleaned up at any time. Also be sure to show how your function is being called.

Comment: I'll edit into the question body, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the correct arguments to your function. Try `add90days(2019, 9, 30)`

Comment: when you pass `datetime.date` to your function, it already is a date. so, just add the `timedelta`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is necro post and late but I had to answer.   The only thing you need in your function is below.

```
new_date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
return new_date
```